# JavaScript, mocha test for random numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I use the following code which return array of random numbers 
my question is how should I unit test it with mocha and chai since the issue here that is provide in every run random numbers...

```
var randomArray = function(start, end) {
  var range = [];
  var resetRange = function() {
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
      range.push(i);
    }
    shuffle(range);
  };

  return function(n) {
    if (range.length === 0) {
      resetRange();
    }
    return range.splice(0, n);
  };
};


var arr = randomArray(10,20);
```

`arr(10)` will provide for example

```
[15, 16, 14, 17, 11, 19, 18, 10, 12, 13]
```

`arr(3)` will provide for example

```
[18, 15, 10]
```

Comment: So, what do yo want expect? whether returns a number or which random number returns?

Comment: @JuanPicado - not sure I want to verify that the functionality is working so im opend for idea...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can obviously verify number of elements.
2. You can run it twice (or various times) and verify that elements are varying (in chai [`assert.notDeepEqual`](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_notdeepequal)).
3. If each element is from certain range, you can verify that also. Just loop through the generated array and verify that each element is greater than `start` and less than `end`.
4. You can test Point #3 with different `start` and `end` values.
5. Test edge cases `start` and `end`, e.g. for `start > end`, `start === end`, `start < 0`, ....

It depends on level of confidence you want to achieve and time you can spent on that testing.

Examples of some points I mentioned (in ES5 syntax as question is using it):

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;

var testLength = function(length) {
    // WHEN
    var actualLength = randomArray(10, 20)(length).length;

    // THEN
    assert.equal(actualLength, length);
};

var testElementsRange = function(start, end) {
    // WHEN
    var actualArray = randomArray(10, 20)(10);

    // THEN
    for (var index = 0; index < actualArray.length; ++index) {
        assert.isAtLeast(actualArray[index], start);
        assert.isAtMost(actualArray[index], end);
    }
}

describe('randomArray', function() {
    describe('generates array', function() {
        it('with length 3', function() {
            testLength(3);
        });

        it('with length 10', function() {
            testLength(10);
        });

        it('with random elements', function () {
            // WHEN
            var array1 = randomArray(10, 20)(10);
            var array2 = randomArray(10, 20)(10);

            // THEN
            assert.notDeepEqual(array1, array2);
        });

        it('with elements within 10-20 range', function () {
            testElementsRange(10, 20);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks 1+, can you  please provide example how would you test it?

Comment: Some examples added